# How can i kill all process except sshd and networking in Linux

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I want to restore my Linux from backup. I searched the internet and find that i have to kill process except `SSHD` and `Networking` and `chkconfig` to  start the restore command

which is basically overiting the `/` from the backup.

1. How can i kill all other process
2. Can i restore backup from remote ssh session or i need to be at computer terminal

Comment: The best way to restore an OS from a backup is to do that without having the OS running. (Read: boot from a CD, a pen drive, an external harddisk, ... anything but the disks you are going to restore to).

Comment: Also, make sure that you are not trying to 'restore' /dev/ or /proc/.

Comment: @Hennes If i had two separate systems will my old users , like /home/user3 dirs stay as it is or they will be removed like backup had 3 users but server where i am restoring had 5 users with home dirs

Comment: Is /home/users3 a directory on /, or it is a separate partition? (Normally one would use different partitions from /, /var/, /usr/local and /home). If it is a partition then simply do not mount it during reinstallation and the contents will stay intact.

Comment: @Hennes , it was my home testng server nothing imp. i dont have separate partition, all in one partition. now i had separate logins on that centos and in backup i had login which were on live Ec2 server. if i overrite that , can i be able to login in old logins or new server logins

Answer (score 1):

Try init 1.  This will take you to runlevel 1 which is single user mode.  From there, you can start the networking service, start SSH and be fairly sure no other process is messing with your filesystem.

Comment: i did that and restored all files in run level 1. when i press reboot then now i got terminal on `grub` how can i type ther kernel path there to reboot